# Converts the given word to the corresponding digit.If the word isn't a valid name returns -1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

How can I write a code that would return -1 If the word isn't a valid digit string and number if it's valid, it also has to accept mixed strings that's why I used lowercase(),I already tried it but some of the strings that i enter wont work , for example one doesn't give me 1 as an output , but zero works for example, what's the problem here ?

```
namespace ProgrammingAssignment4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts words to digits
    /// </summary>
    public class Digitizer
    {
        #region Fields

        // declare your Dictionary field and create the Dictionary object for it here
        Dictionary<string, int> digitizer = new Dictionary<string, int>();
         

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Digitizer()
        {


            digitizer.Add("zero", 0);
            digitizer.Add("ONe", 1);
            digitizer.Add("tWo", 2);
            digitizer.Add("three", 3);
            digitizer.Add("four", 4);
            digitizer.Add("six", 6);
            digitizer.Add("seven", 7); ;
            digitizer.Add("nine", 9);
            digitizer.Add("bob", -1);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the given word to the corresponding digit.
        /// If the word isn't a valid digit name, returns -1
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word">word to convert</param>
        /// <returns>corresponding digit or -1</returns>
        public int ConvertWordToDigit(string word)
        {
            word.Cast<Digitizer>(); 

            if (word.ToLower().Contains("zero"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["zero"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                
            }
            else if (word.ToLower().Contains("ONe"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["ONe"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
           else if (word.ToLower().Contains("tWo"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["tWo"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
           else if (word.ToLower().Contains("three"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["three"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            else if (word.ToLower().Contains("four"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["four"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            } else if (word.ToLower().Contains("six"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["six"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            } else if (word.ToLower().Contains("seven"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["seven"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            } else if (word.ToLower().Contains("nine"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["nine"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            else if (word.ToLower().Contains("bob"))
            {
                int value = digitizer["bob"];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            return -1;
            #endregion
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just ask if the `digitizer` `ContainsKey()` the `word.ToLower()` ?

Comment: `word.ToLower().Contains("ONe")` will never be true; can you work out why?

Comment: I'm not sure , but I guess because I'm comparing it with a lower cased string "one" ?

Comment: Yes; C# is case sensitive, so a string of `"one"` will never contains=true for an input of `"ONe"`

Answer (score 0):

Go with something like this;

```
namespace ProgrammingAssignment4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts words to digits
    /// </summary>
    public class Digitizer
    {
        #region Fields
        // declare your Dictionary field and create the Dictionary object for it here
        Dictionary<string, int> digitizer = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Digitizer()
        {
            digitizer.Add("zero", 0);
            digitizer.Add("ONe", 1);
            digitizer.Add("tWo", 2);
            digitizer.Add("three", 3);
            digitizer.Add("four", 4);
            digitizer.Add("six", 6);
            digitizer.Add("seven", 7); ;
            digitizer.Add("nine", 9);
            digitizer.Add("bob", -1);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the given word to the corresponding digit.
        /// If the word isn't a valid digit name, returns -1
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word">word to convert</param>
        /// <returns>corresponding digit or -1</returns>
        public int ConvertWordToDigit(string word)
        {
            if (!digitizer.ContainsKey(word))
                return -1;
            else
                return digitizer[word];
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

You could also make all you words lowercase and use

```
        public int ConvertWordToDigit(string word)
        {
            if (!digitizer.ContainsKey(word.ToLower()))
                return -1;
            else
                return digitizer[word.ToLower()];
        }
```

..but remember to make your `digitizer.Add("ONe", 1);` into `digitizer.Add("one", 1);` (and the same with your `"tWo"` etc). Also, you don't need `digitizer.Add("bob", -1);` at all

Comment: Thank you very much I followed what you said and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

In your ConvertWordToDigit()-method you compare a lowered string to a non-lowered string. And "one" != "ONe". In order to compare, you have to lower both values.

```
string wordToCompare = "ONe";

else if (word.ToLower().Contains(wordToCompare.ToLower()))
{
    int value = digitizer[wordToCompare.ToLower()];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I don't think so , because I already added "ONe" within my dictionary ! why would I create another one , i guess its just a waste of memory and not efficient , right ?

Comment: I just took a part of the original code and tried to show, that it compares "one" with "ONe". The sample does not add an extra dicationary, just made an extra variable to make ist more clear.